# CSS menu dropping over a siFR title breaks in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, menu, sifr, drop-down-menu

I've tried setting the z-indexes accordingly.. the sifR'd title is in wmode = transparent... I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?  It doesn't work in both IE 6 and 7.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the element that the SIFR SWF is in isn't set as:

```
position: relative;
```

That will also cause the SWF to render on top of your menu rather than under.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/about), it' similar to siFR, but it doesn't use Flash.